# 13.10 to 14.04 LTS Firefox, email and desktop problems

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, firefox, gmail

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS last week. There are a few problems:

**Outlook**: keeps saying to upgrade to the newest Firefox (Firefox says it's the most updated version), it won't load properly giving me an error screen then "proceed to inbox anyway". I cannot right click or highlight anything. I cannot make changes to the settings.

**Gmail**: Can't right click or highlight anything

I was thinking it might be a problem with Firefox since the upgrade. But haven't found any Firefox forums yet with the same issues.

I am also having general problems with serious lagging and the mouse/pointer while navigating around the desktop.

Running:

- Sony Vaio with Intel® Core™ i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
- 32-bit
- 272.1 GB disk
- 5.9 GiB total memory (dual platform with Windows 7)

**Q**: Are there settings or plug-ins I may be missing? Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance!